# POST request gets 405 response instead of being handled by access-denied-handler

Tags: java, spring, post, spring-security, http-status-code-405

This happens in a Spring MVC application where Spring Security is also used. I have configured request with mapping "`/user/save`" so that only admins have access to it:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/user/save/**" access="hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_OPERATOR'"/>
```

Unauthorized requests are handled by

```
<access-denied-handler error-page="/denied"/>
```

When I make `/user/save` request having only `ROLE_OPERATOR` I get the following warning:

```
WARN http-nio-8080-exec-20 servlet.PageNotFound:208 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

and `/denied` doesn't get hit. Why?

Answers to similar problems propose configuring csrf for POST queries, but POST queries work for `ROLE_ADMIN` so that shouldn't be the problem here.

I tried specifying method types in security configuration like  this:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/user/save/**" access="hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')" method="GET"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/user/save/**" access="hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')" method="POST"/>
```

but it didn't help.

Access denied handler works correctly in other cases, gets hit when requests are made with insufficient privileges, so that shouldn't be a part of the problem either.

What could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem was in the controller method for `/denied` request. It had a GET version, but not a POST version. Adding a POST version like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/denied", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Response userAccessDeniedForPost() {
    ...
}
```

solved the problem.